# AWS Fargate container exiting instead of Autoscaling causing 502 error

Tags: load-balancing, cpu, autoscaling, aws-fargate, http-status-code-502

I Configured fargate autoscaling with minimum capacity as 2  and autoscaling metrics as CPU utilization of 70% but when we start test, 1 container is running  and after 4 minutes, it gets exited  with autoscaling peak cpu 95% and memory 81.3%.After a delay of 2 minutes, new container  got started and during this 2 minutes, we experienced  502 errors, 504 and 503. What can be the cause

I tried autoscaling from the initial one container to 2 minimum and desired capacity and also reduce cpu utilization from 80 to 70% but it had little to no effect as the minimum capacity still stayed as 1

Comment: Is your ECS deployment completing successfully? The autoscaling changes will only apply to the new deployment, but if that is not successful, you will probably continue to see the old autoscaling settings. If you have healthchecks configured for the service, they must pass in order for the deployment to succeed, but that may not happen if you're getting 5xx errors or containers exiting unexpectedly.

Comment: @sytech changes made directly to the auto-scaling configuration affect the ECS service immediately. They do not wait for the next deployment to take effect. Changes to Desired Count should almost immediately change the number of tasks ECS is running for a given service.

Comment: @MarkB I see. You're right. I was under the mistaken impression it would trigger a deployment.